# Selenium IE driver not able to find the correct page source

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a login page which redirects to a page from where I need to extract some data from an element using selenium.
I am running the code from local eclipse using the IE driver but facing an issue as the pagesource is that of the initial web driver page after some time the IE browser does navigate to the page with some delay , but the page source remains the same and get a exception as no such element found.

Have tried to add implicity waits but did not work.
Any work around where I can induce a delay ?

`DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        File file = new File("D:/IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps); 
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));`

Comment: try explicit waits instead of implicit

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi Jdelorean , have added the code ..

Comment: Have also tried explicit wait..the problem I am facing is when I get the pagetitle it shows 'WebDriver' which is the initial page of the driver..but doesn't navigate beyond that point

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment (to your question) that "It does not navigate beyond the first page of the driver having title 'WebDriver'", I gather you are not able to go to login page, enter credentials and click on some button that will redirect to 2nd page.

In that case, please make you that you are using appropriate version of Internet Explorer driver. I am using 64-bit version of Internet Explorer driver as I am using 64-bit version of Internet Explorer browser and 64-bit OS on my PC. If you are using 32-bit version of Internet Explorer browser and 32-bit OS, you will need to use 32-bit version of Internet Explorer driver. How to find which version of Internet Explorer browser we are using: By checking path of it's executable file, whether it is in "Program Files" or in "Program Files (x86)" folder. How to see whether OS is 32 bit or 64 bit: Right-click on "Computer" and select "Properties".

I think following code would work:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Dependancies/IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("URL_of_login_page"); // Make sure the URL begins with 'http' or 'https'.
    // Enter login credentials, click on 'Submit' button so that it will redirect to 2nd page.
    Thread.sleep(15000); // Assuing 15 seconds is sufficient time for the 2nd page to load.
    System.out.println("The 2nd page is loaded now.");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // It should print page-title of 2nd page.
    String source;
    source = driver.getPageSource();
    System.out.println(source); 
}
```

Comment: I see I have a 32 bit version of OS.. and a 32 bit of IE ..but still gives out an error..also checked with a 64 bit IEDriver but shows incompatibility error.

Comment: 64-bit won't work then. You need download Internet Explorer Driver from here: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1.zip 
After extracting above .zip file, wherever you keep the exe file, that path you need to provide in System.setProperty() method.
Can you post which error are you getting after doing above?

Comment: downloaded the version also ran the program , the main issue is after the intial web driver url ..the page is physically redirected to the destination page, but when I do a driver.getpagesource() I get the webdriver url source rather than the new page source.

Comment: for instane --- www.google.com is my base url ---> redirects automatically to -www.wikipedia.org ..when is start the driver and open the page..the driver page is the pagesource always..it never gets the source of redirected page

Comment: Disclaimer: This comment is not solution. Just information. This seems to be a known problem as discussed on: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/232 (WebDriver is not working properly with pages after HTTP redirect in IE?) The last comment by lukeis says it was resolved by using Protractor (http://www.protractortest.org/#/) which is used for AngularJS applications.